# Keep on getting No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, siteminder

I am learning and need to configure siteminder SSO with Spring Security. I followed some blog and wrote my code as fllowing. Plz help to resolove: "No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined" error. Here is my code:

web.xml

```
<context-param> 
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/conf/Security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>     

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Security-config.xml

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
        <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>   

<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.cno.cnofdw.security.CustomUserDetailsService"></bean>
<bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"></bean>
```

Placed Security-config.xml under WEB-INF/conf/
Even I tried importing  in applicationContext.xml. but no use.

Can anybody help me to resolve this problem and if possible please suggest any blog to configure spring with siteminder signle sign on?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What blog did you follow? care to provide a link?

Comment: Good to hear from you katzenhut! here is the blog that I followed: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/08/11/spring-3-security-siteminder-pre-authentication-example/

Answer (score 0):

Your missing "/" in path. It should be:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/conf/Security-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: No its not "/".. My contextConfigLocation never read. dont know why?         <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/Security-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: Other option to try is: place Security-config.xml file under WEB-INF directory without conf directory i.e: /WEB-INF/Security-config.xml

Comment: One more option as per http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/tutorial_security.html: <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

Comment: tried the same. If I move applicationContext under WEB-INF, its not loading because I am using ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml"); to load.               that Security-config.xml never detected. even if I wrongly typed the file name like Security111111-config.xml, its not displaying error, however saying no bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined. My mind blowing :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all who spent time to answer my question. I have placed contextClass in my web.xml and I have commented it and got resolved.

contextClass
                   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext